# Android Bump API

Tags: android, bump

I have a problem on android bump API when i first run the bump on my application it is fine but when i try it the second time my application closes automatically when i check the log it say:

```
A/libc(12139): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1)
```

i think the problem is the unbindService(connection) that is onDestroy method somehow it did not stop the service so when you try to configure it the second time it will get the fatal signal error due to the service that is already configure.

Comment: I am also stuck to this point. Did you get any solution for this?
Please help.

Comment: i'm still finding some fix to this issue

Comment: Hey did you get any solution for this... still searching for the same issue :(
tried using singleton but did not work

Comment: i haven't found any solution yetnow we've stop doing bump function for our application we will wait for the bump API to update maybe they can fix the error

Answer (score 6):

You have to make a service like location service and just call it once in your application and just use  bump register and unregister in your activity on which you want to use bump and send or receive data